# In Perl, how can I join an input line with the next one only if some condition is satisfied?

Tags: perl

My lines

```
Line: foobar, foo
Line: webar, webar, we
Line: 
abcabc
abc
Line: 
xyzxyz
xyz
```

What I want to do is to join them into one lines:

```
Line: foobar, foo
Line: webar, webar, we
Line: abcabc, abc
Line: xyzxyz, xyz
```

Comment: I am guessing somewhere there is some school or employer asking this question. There seems to be a proliferation of how do I join one line with the next if *something* type questions. To do OP: What do you think will happen if you pass without knowing or take the job without understanding?

Answer (score 0):

One method is to read the whole file in and split on `\nLine:` and then do some fixups to the data.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $data = <<EOF;
Line: foobar, foo
Line: quxbar, quxbar, quxx
Line: 
abcabc
abc
EOF

$data =~ s/^Line: //;
my @lines = split("\nLine: ", $data);
s/\n/, /g for @lines;

print join "\n", map { "Line: $_" } @lines;
```

Comment: Run your code -- there is an additional `, ` after the 3rd `Line: `

Answer (score -1):

*script.pl*:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

my @lines;

while(<>) {
        chomp;

        if(m/^Line: /) {
                push @lines, $_;
        }
        else {
                if(length $lines[-1] == 6) {
                        $lines[-1] .= $_;
                }
                else {
                        $lines[-1] .= ", $_";
                }
        }
}

print "$_\n" for @lines;
```

Save your example input as file *file* and run

```
cat file | perl script.pl
```

Comment: The 'cat' is an unnecessary waste of a process.  Simply do: perl script.pl file

Comment: `say for @lines` looks a bit better.

Comment: @TLP: yes, I agree, but I try to avoid features that are not available in Perl5 by default unless I know we have a recent Perl.

Comment: On the other hand, you should encourage people to upgrade to new perl versions, and new features.