# In Perl, how can I join an input line with the next one only if the first one ends with a colon?

Tags: perl

My lines:

```
ABC: XYZ
XYZ ABC: XYZ
XYZ:
ABC
XYZ
ABC:
AAB
CCD
```

I want to join lines end with colon, with next line:

```
ABC: XYZ
XYZ ABC: XYZ
XYZ: ABC
XYZ
ABC: AAB
CCD
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Perl, how can I join an input line with the next one only if some condition is satisfied?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8012880/in-perl-how-can-i-join-an-input-line-with-the-next-one-only-if-some-condition-i)

Comment: @Sinan You’re right, but gosh those are all bad answers.

Comment: @tchrist If, as I suspect, these are homework or interview questions, worse answers might be better ;-)

Comment: @sinan The chutzpah of kids asking other people to do their homework for them leaves me stunned. This was grounds for expulsion when I was at university, and there was no room for appeal. You did your own work, period. Anything else is cheating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the content fits in memory, load it into a single variable and do this:

```
$text =~ s/:\n/: /g
```

Comment: Even if the content can fit in memory, slurping is the wrong answer in almost 99.99% of cases.

Comment: 99.99% of cases? Personally i would just do whatever involves less typing. Is that wrong?

Comment: @DanDman False laziness is not a virtue.  Write algorithms that scale, not which explode.

Comment: @tchrist tchrist -- the Confucius of Perl.

Answer (score 1):

My attempt at a more aesthetically pleasing version.

```
while (<DATA>) {
  chomp;
  print $_;
  print /:$/ ? " " : "\n";
}
```

Older, unpleasing attempt.
This answer only keeps the current line in memory, it does not require slurping the input nor building the entire output in memory.  It also handles empty data correctly, no prints if no input.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $text;
while( my $line = <DATA> ) {
  if ($line =~ /:\s*\n/ && defined $text) {
      print $text;
      undef $text;
  }
  $line =~ s/:\s*\n/: /g;
  $text .= $line;
}
print $text if defined $text;

__DATA__
ABC: XYZ
XYZ ABC: XYZ
XYZ:
ABC
XYZ
ABC:
AAB
CCD
```

Comment: You have the same regex in two places.  This seems very complicated.

Comment: Trying for correctness and minimal memory rather than simplicity.

Comment: Simplicity brings clarity.  In algorithms just as in proofs, the simpler and cleaner, the more aesthetically pleasing. Why do you have two variables? Why does this ever require more than one accumulator variable?

Comment: I was starting with code copied from below and making minimal changes.  I need the built up text waiting to be printed and the line coming in that may be added to current output linet or used to start new output line.  I was lazily using the undef status of $text as a state variable.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to fix the file, use this commandline:

```
% perl -i.orig -pe 'chomp if /:$/' yourfile
```

If you're in an input loop and want to cuddle records ending in colons, do:

```
while (<>) {
    chomp;
    if (/:$/ && !eof) {
         $_ .= <>;
         redo unless eof;
    }
    # now you have your cuddled line(s), proceed as before
    ...
}
```

This assumes that the last line of your file is not a continuation line.

Comment: Mighty big assumption since it goes into an infinite loop if the last line is a continuation!  Love the one-liner though.

Comment: @Bill That’s why I mentioned the assumption. A liberal dose of `unless eof` would take care of that, but it isn’t very useful on a tty.

Comment: Just needs "redo unless eof;"

Comment: isn't the eof case in the if covered by the while?

Comment: Instead of all this complexity, how something simple: (a) replace colon-newline with colon-space; (b) print.

Comment: @Bill: No, the while does not cover the eof case.  Consider the last line of the file, as always.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $emit_eol;

while( my $line = <DATA> ) {
    $emit_eol = ($line =~ s/ : \s+ \z /: /x);
    print $line;
}

print "\n" if $emit_eol;

__DATA__
ABC: XYZ
XYZ ABC: XYZ
XYZ:
ABC
XYZ
ABC:
AAB
CCD:
```

Comment: These questions are poorly posed, as it is not possible to determine whether they just want a trivial program to join up continuation lines as a filter or file-munger, or whether this is actually asking how to modify an existing input loop to account for said continuations.

Answer (score 0):

```
my $text;
{
  local $/= "";
  $text = <DATA>;
  $text =~ s/:\n/: /g;
}
print $text;

__DATA__
ABC: XYZ
XYZ ABC: XYZ
XYZ:
ABC
XYZ
ABC:
AAB
CCD
```

Answer (score 0):

Both suggestions so far recommend slurping the file into memory, however this isn't strictly necessary given original question.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $text;
while( my $line = <DATA> ) {
    if ($line =~ s/ : \s+ \z /: /x) {
        $text .= $line;
    }
    else {
        print $text if is_nonempty_string($text);
        print $line;
        $text = '';
    }
}

print $text, "\n" if is_nonempty_string($text);

sub is_nonempty_string { defined($_[0]) and length($_[0]) }

__DATA__
ABC: XYZ
XYZ ABC: XYZ
XYZ:
ABC
XYZ
ABC:
AAB
CCD:
```

Comment: Does a print on empty input, holds entire output in memory.

Comment: I tried to improve on the original solution without changing the spirit of it. Feel free to rollback the changes.

Comment: ok I guess I was going a bit fast this morning. Thanks Sinan. It does seem like this task should be simpler.

Comment: Though truthfully, the empty input thing doesn't worry me. This appears to be a one-off, so lets assume that its being used for something. Not to mention, the print was for display, not the final use. If the OP wants a permanent fix, let em try, it would seem that edge cases abound.